# Remove new lines and tabs in luajson output

Tags: json, lua

I'm trying to convert a saved Lua table into something I can parse more easily for inclusion on a web page.  I'm using Lua for windows from [code.google's luaforwindows](https://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/).  It has included in it this [harningt's luajson](https://github.com/harningt/luajson) for handling this conversion.  I've been able to figure out how to load in the contents of the file.  I get no errors, but the "json" it produces is invalid. it just encloses the entire thing in quotes and adds `\n` and `\t`.  The file I'm reading is a `.lua` file, which follows the format:

```
MyBorrowedData = {
    ["first"] = {
        ["firstSub"] = {
            ["firstSubSub"] = {
                {
                    ["stuffHere"]="someVal"
                },
                {
                    ["stuffHere2"]="some2Val"
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Note the `,` following the final item in each "row" of the table, is that the issue?  Is it valid Lua data?  I feel like given the output, Lua is unable to parse the table when I read it in.  I believe this even more when I try to just `require` the lua data file, and I seem to be unable to iterate through the table manually.

Can anyone tell me if it's a bug in the code or poorly formatted data that's causing the issue?

The Lua lifting is easy:

```
local json = require("json")
local file = "myBorrowedData.lua"
local jsonOutput = "myBorrowedOutput.json"

r = io.input(file)
t = io.read('*all')
u = io.output(jsonOutput)
s = json.encode(t)
io.write(s)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading the file as plain text, and not loading the Lua code contained inside of it. `t` becomes a string with the Lua file's contents, which of course serializes to a plain JSON string.

To serialize the data in the Lua file, you need to run it.

```
local func = loadstring(lua_code_string) -- Load Lua code from string
local data = {} -- Create table to store data
setfenv(func, data) -- Set the loaded function's environment, so any global writes that func does will go to the data table instead.
func() -- Run the loaded function.

local serialized_out = json.encode(data)
```

Also, ending the last item of a table with a comma (or semicolon) is perfectly valid syntax. In fact, I recommend it; you don't need to worry about adding a comma to the former last object when adding new items to the table.

Comment: After I posted the question, I took my code and pasted it at the bottom of the lua file and it worked, so I had a feeling I wasn't loading the data correctly.  I had to figure out implementation of your answer, but once I did, BOOM, success!   Thank you very much.
  If anyone is interested  I put the code right after my original t var and changed his lua_code_string to my t var.  The s var was changed to json.encode(data).

Comment: @AndyFoster Please consider using more descriptive variable names. For the cost of a few more keypresses, you make your code much more understandable to other people (such as us on SO) as well as yourself.

Comment: Will do so, I do this in JS all the time, I don't know why i didn't change them as I was cherry picking.